# How to call angular function from android button on click?

Tags: android, angularjs, webview

I'm trying to load angular function in android `webView.LoadUrl` I am using following android activity code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);   
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
webView.loadUrl("http://www.foobar.com/test");
```

on a button click from android I wanted to call a function written in Angular. 
I tried with following attempts which are not working:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:$scope.testFunction()");
    // webView.loadUrl("javascript:testFunction()");
  }         
});
```

I think the function `testFunction()` is attached to the controller not in global that is why I'm unable to call it by either methods. can someone suggest me how to follow it and call an angular function written inside some controller by a custom button clicked from Android:

```
$scope.testFunction = function(){
  $log.log('You have successfully called the function written in AngularJS');
  $window.alert('You have successfully called the function written in AngularJS')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need a [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/zhoulujue/WebViewJavascriptBridge), and that works for me!

Comment: Okay I will try your suggestion and post you Thanks.